# Byte representation of a text file

Tags: byte

I heard that everything on the hard disk are stored as blocks of bytes. If that is the case, what would be the byte representation of a text file?

For example, I have this text.txt on my Mac computer

```
Hello,
World!
```

I wonder what the corresponding bytes look like? Should I expect every character translated to its ASCII code? Where on my machine can I find the bytes? It would be nice to have something pre-installed on a typical Mac/linux to view the binary/hex representation of the text file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character encoding used when writing a text file is between you and your text editor. Almost certainly not ASCII; Probably, the UTF-8 character of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. Only you will know because that metadata is not saved with the file.

When reading, a text editor will guess but you should be able to correct it. Other programs either allow you to tell them via a command-line argument or document which you must give it.

This effectively makes text files useless for casual users.

To view bytes of a file in hexadecimal:

```
xxd -g1 filepath
```

The file system will store the name, location and size of a file. Programs reading files will stop at the end of the file rather than read all the allocated disk blocks. Also note that the file system doesn't store whether a file is a text file or not. Again, only you know that.

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand that the file system only sees bits, not how those bits should be interpreted.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, everything on your computer is a number.
In hexadecimal notation,
H is 48, e is 65, l is 6C, o is 6F, the comma is 2C, next line is 0A, W is 57, etc. and finally the exclamation mark is 21.
There are programs that show this "internal" representation of any characters.

Comment: Thanks. How to quickly get the hex rep. of a text file?

Comment: Just type "ASCII" in your Google : you'll find plenty of tables on net Net. But ASCII is just the beginning. Nowadays every character of ANY languague (including Chinese, Japanese, Hebrew, etc.) is coded with Unicode. Type "Unicode" in Google !

Comment: Is there anything pre-installed on a typical  Mac/linux to view the binary/hex representation of a text file?

Comment: Don't know much about Mac but I don't think so : Few users want to know how data are represented at a low level !